# Pseudo upload de arquivo com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Minha intenção é fazer um pseudo-upload de um arquivo qualquer, quando digo pseudo me refiro ao fato que: ele nao deve ir para o servidor.. e transforma-lo em `base64`

Tipo, eu seleciono uma imagem X mas ao invez de ela ser `upada` normalmente para o servidor ela é transformada em base64 do lado do browser. é possível fazer isto com Javascript? Qual a funçao eu deveria usar?

Comment: Por pseudo-upload eu acho que você quer dizer "leitura", você quer acessar arquivos locais usando javascript? Se for esse o caso, você usa a API File + HTML 5. Tutorial completo [aqui](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua dúvida é somente como transformar um arquivo em base64:

Utilize a função [`FileReader#readAsDataURL`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsDataURL) para ler o arquivo. Depois de lido, pode utilizar [`FileReader#result`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-result) para obter o resultado.

<kbd>[ver navegadores que suportam](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader)</kbd>

```js
function toBase64() {
  // obtém o arquivo
  var file = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
  // obtém uma instância de FileReader
  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  // Faz a leitura do arquivo
  if (file) {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  
  // Quando concluir a leitura, o resultado é inserido no parágrafo 'output'
  fileReader.onloadend = function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = fileReader.result;
  };
}
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='toBase64()' />
<p id='output'></p>
```

No site da *Mozilla Developer Network* há [um exemplo bem interessante](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) que utiliza o resultado lido pelo `FileReader` como valor do atributo `src` de uma `img`, segue:

```js
/**
 * SRC:
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL
 */

function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```